# django - use result of annotate in subsequent annotate

Tags: python, django, annotate

I have the following model structure:

```
Model A:
    [no question-relevant fields]

Model B:
    linked_to = ForeignKey(A, related_name='involved')
    date = DateField()
    amount = IntegerField()
```

what I'm trying to do is getting for each object A all the related model B, from this subset getting the latest one by date, then calculate the sum of all the model B with the same date and the same connected A object.

Right now I'm using this query:

```
A.objects.all().annotate(latest_date=Max('involved__date'))
```

This return the correct latest date for each A object, next I'm trying:

```
A.objects.all().annotate(latest_date=Max('involved__date')).annotate(total=Sum(Case(When(involved__date=F('latest_date'), then='involved__amount'))))
```

But I'm getting a

`AttributeError: 'Case' object has no attribute 'name'`.

I've used multiple annotate before, without any issue, the difference is that in the past I always used previous annotated values coming from existing field, never from a Max/Min, so I'm not sure if this makes the difference.

Django version is 1.8

I cannot use any raw SQL here and I know this can be easily done in 2 steps, but at this point is more a personal curiosity of understanding how this works.

Comment: Have you tried using `then=F('involved__amount')`

Comment: yes, same error unfortunately, I think the 'then' part is correct, because while trying different solution I hardcoded the date and it worked